# I need a batch program to find the folder name inside another folder

Tags: sql, email, batch-file, find

For example

consider:

```
H:\reports\test\12345\dailynews.pdf
```

I want to send this `PDF` through mail by using `MSSQL` job (sql server 2008 R2).
But every time when another job creates the `pdf` file the location changes.
like

```
H:\reports\test\48596\dailynews.pdf
```

I need a batch program to find the folder name which is present after the test folder.

Comment: And what is your question? [SO] isn't a script writing service but a site for programmers helping other programmers when they got stuck with a distinct problem.

Comment: Hi Lotpings...  I know that stack overflow is not script writing service.

Comment: If you don't document your own effort with posting the code **you** have - it looks like a request to write the code for you - and that could get you voted down and the question closed for being too broad.

Comment: I got your point. It's not that I didn't put my efforts.  As I work on VDI to the production support environment  it is not possible to copy the code and I don't have access to Google here. I need to use the general system which are outside my bay. Hope u understand my problems :)

Comment: Do you have the full path, and want to know the name of the parent folder? Or do you not know which folder(s) under `H:\reports\test` contains the dailynews.pdf, and you want to find it? Either way, both questions have been asked and answered before.

Comment: The path I mentioned has a folder named 12345 which always keeps on changing as I generate the report. That folder is a process ID folder. When ever a new report is generated the new process ID folder is created and inside that folder report is generated.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more useful. Still I am unsure, if it covers your problem. According to your last comment, I think that you dont know how to find the latest report. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the given info, I would suggest to
split the string at the backslashes and extract the 4th element like this:

```
set p=H:\reports\test\12345\dailynews.pdf
for /F "delims=\ tokens=4" %%a in ("%p%") do echo %%a
```

Note the double quotes `("%p%")`, so it gets interpreted as string (and not as a filename or command).

If you want to make sure, that the 3rd element is the `test` folder, then I would suggest:

```
set p=H:\reports\test\12345\dailynews.pdf
set o=H:\reports\live\55555\dailynews.pdf

for /F "delims=\ tokens=3,4" %%a in ("%p%") do if "%%a"=="test" echo %%b
for /F "delims=\ tokens=3,4" %%a in ("%o%") do if "%%a"=="test" echo %%b
```

Outputs `12345` but not `55555`, which is in the `live` folder.

---

Edit:
I realized that my answer left out completely, how one can detect the newest `dailynews.pdf`, which is what the OP probably looking for.
Like the dailynews routine runs at 21.00, and you want to mail that report at 22.00. (Again, yet another assumption.)

IMO, the tricky part is to parse and compare the date/time info of the files.
A simple `dir dailynews.txt /S /O:-D` does not work with subdirs.

So...

```
@echo off
cls

set base=H:\reports\test
set filename=dailynews.pdf

set current_date=19000101
set current_time=0000
set current_file=

::debug output
dir "%filename%" /S /O:-D

:: inspect each entry
for /F "usebackq" %%a in (`dir "%filename%" /S /B /O:-D`) do call :inspect "%%a"

:: all done, quit
goto :quit

:: subroutine for comparing current with actual newest entry
:inspect
echo %1

set _date=
set _time=

:: get comparable date time info
:: change to your regional date/time settings/locale! (german here)
:: maybe check SO for other locales
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=.: " %%a in (`dir %1^|findstr "%filename%"`) do echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e&set _date=%%c%%b%%a&set _time=%%d%%e

:: we have to split in two components, otherwise it seems too big for comparing
if /I %_date% LSS %current_date% goto :eof
if /I %_time% LSS %current_time% goto :eof

:: this one is newer! set new values
set current_date=%_date%
set current_time=%_time%
set current_file=%1

goto :eof


:quit
set current_
```

Performance may get worse if you dont clean up the basedir at some time.

Comment: That's a good answer to question **not** asked - that was a feature request. To get `p` you should first recursively search `For /R "H:\reports\test" %%P in (dailynews.pdf) Do ...`

Comment: Well, I assumed/"read" the question: "How to find folder name after test?" But thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Please explain downvote.

Comment: You'll never know who voted down, but I personally can live with the ratio - he lost 1, you 2 but the  2 up votes got you 20 rep - 10 from me ;-)

Comment: There is a much better way to do this that does not care how many folders are in the path. But I'm not yet sure if this is what the OP is looking for. (btw - I did not down vote).

Answer (score 1):

A recursive check may report same named files existing elsewhere in the tree and may take longer. My suggestion is to use this instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "MyFile="
For /D %%A In ("H:\reports\test\*"
) Do If Exist "%%A\dailynews.pdf" Set "MyFile=%%~fA\dailynews.pdf"
If Not Defined MyFile Exit/B
Echo %%MyFile%% = %MyFile%
```